# Fontforge: `some fragments did not join` - how can I find this fragments?

Tags: inkscape, font-forge

Sometimes I can see the problem and connect the dots, but sometimes I just do not see where the fragments are not connected. For example this letter:

[image: Fontforge]

What can you recommend? I importing svg from Inkscape – maybe I can fix something inside Inkscape to prevent this error?

[image: Inkscape font editing]

Comment: A few notes on what I am seeing: 1) Do you really want only the outline of the *H* to be black in your font? If yes, you should almost certainly work with a *stroked font (element → font info → layers → stroked font).* 2) You should have nodes at the vertical and horizontal local extrema of your paths. If not, the font rendering at small sizes will look horrible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Element → Validation → Validate* complains about open paths and selects the end notes for you. Note that this is the *Element* menu from the font view, not from the glyph view.

(For your font, it will complain about a lot more things; consider them.)

[image: fontforge validate]

Comment: `Element` menu not have the `Validation`... version of `FontForge` from `24-Aug-2015`

Comment: @VitalyZdanevich: I do not know about that particular version, but I just built FontForge directly from the source and it does have the *Validation* menu. Note my [edit](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/posts/67575/revisions) though.

Answer (score 0):

When using paste (Ctrl+v) vectors from Inkscape then You should have "stroke style" width zeroed out. If not, then you will end up with two lines according to thickness of the lines. So better to have filled up vector with zero stoke width.
I don't know if this is true when importing vectors to Fontforge from Inkscape but logically it should be so.
One think to keep an eye is to have correct direction of paths in Fontforge.
I change point and line colors in resource manager to easier see where are open paths, missing extremes  and more..

[image]

I usually do the following when importing or copy/paste vectors from Inkscape.
In fontview window (where you edit fonts)

1. Crtl+a to select all the points
2. Crtl+Shift+x to add extrema points
3. Crtl+a to select all the points (you made a new points so this selects those)
4. Crtl+Shift+_ to round points to integers
5. Crtl+Shift+m to clean up points
   this all I do twice and then remove/add (un)necessary points manually.
   Hope this helps.
   Cheers Ari